# "Cannot connect to server 'datahost': [Errno -2] Name or service not known", gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')

Tags: python-3.x, docker, host, gitlab-ci

I'm getting this error from gitlab-ci. At `test` stage, I will pull down the latest docker, and run `docker run $LatestImage python /path/to/test.py`, and the error message came from `pytds` as a `pytds.tds.LoginError`. I didn't get this error on local machine because I have set `x.x.x.x datahost` in local `/etc/hosts`. So I added one more docker command before the test command: `docker run -i --add-host datahost:x.x.x.x $LatestImage cat /etc/hosts` and I can see that `datahost` has been added to that image. However, when I run the test, I still got this error. So I don't know if there's anything else I left, to my current research online it should be a "Forgot to set host" problem.